# Proof by Induction hard case

Tags: integration, solution-verification, induction, binomial-coefficients

I'm trying to prove by induction$$\int_0^\infty\frac{x^kdx}{(1+x)^n}=\frac{(n+1)^{-1}}{\binom{n}{k}},\,0<k<n,$$but I'm struggling on the integrating the integral. Any ideas/solutions?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or be closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognize and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: You might want to transform this into human readable text.

Comment: The base case is $n=k+1$; the inductive step is from $n=m\ge k+1$ to $n=m+1$. Are you having trouble with the base case, the inductive step or both? It's a [well-known problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_prime_distribution) that's usually solved without induction, by evaluating the integrals directly (especially since the base step will need that technique anyway), but if we call your integral $I_{k,\,n}$ a recursion relation on it would be needed in any inductive step. Hint: prove $I_{k,\,n}+I_{k+1,\,n}=I_{k,\,n-1}$.